# How to avoid /dev/urandom when using keytool

Tags: ssl, keytool

We use tomcat, weblogic, websphere, apache (basically java) on Linux, Solaris and AIX platforms. For encyption we use SSL. To generate the private/public keypair we use keytool. Articles around java keytool suggest that we avoid the use of /dev/urandom as the entropy device. Given that /dev/urandom is the default, how do we create the private/public keypair without using /dev/urandom ?

Comment: Any pointers to these articles?

Answer (score 0):

The file of interest is in your JRE `lib/security` folder, it's called `java.security`. Inside it you will find the following line:

```
securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom
```

And there are comments in the file describing its behavior. You can switch it to use `/dev/random` instead (which is more secure but due to entropy issues may take a long time) if you need to:

```
#
# Select the source of seed data for SecureRandom. By default an
# attempt is made to use the entropy gathering device specified by 
# the securerandom.source property. If an exception occurs when
# accessing the URL then the traditional system/thread activity 
# algorithm is used. 
#
# On Solaris and Linux systems, if file:/dev/urandom is specified and it
# exists, a special SecureRandom implementation is activated by default.
# This "NativePRNG" reads random bytes directly from /dev/urandom.
#
# On Windows systems, the URLs file:/dev/random and file:/dev/urandom
# enables use of the Microsoft CryptoAPI seed functionality.
#
securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom
#
# The entropy gathering device is described as a URL and can also
# be specified with the system property "java.security.egd". For example,
#   -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom
# Specifying this system property will override the securerandom.source 
# setting.
```

You can see more about [Java policy files here in the Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html#DefaultLocs)

Here is a short tutorial on [overriding default Java security](http://blog.eyallupu.com/2012/11/how-to-overriding-java-security.html) as well